# Solution Is Clearly An Image

Tags: visual, rebus

As the title suggests, the answer is an image.

More specifically, you have to find the 7 character long imgur ID for the image:

> imgur.com/□□□□□□□

Each character can be any letter A-Z (case-sensitive) or a number 0-9.

These are 7 little puzzles you have to solve, each corresponding to one character in the image URL:

> 1st character:
> [image]
>
> 2nd character:
> [image]
>
> 3rd character:
> [image]
>
> 4th character:
> [image]
>
> 5th character:
> [image]
>
> 6th character:
> [image]
>
> 7th character:
> [image]

Good luck!

P.S. I'm not that familiar with the tags, so feel free to suggest edits :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The image is ...

> ... the one with id **J3gt6dw**:
>
>  [image: Super!]
>
>  (The image was first found by Silenius. My first guess had the t wrong.)

1st character:

> **J** — Converting to digits with A1Z26 gives a sum of 10. Converting back yields J.

2nd character:

> **3** — Highlight the cells in a grid that has rows and columns labelled from J to N. The first letter is the column, the second is the row. The highighted cells show the digit 3.

3rd character:

> **g** — The layout shows a column on the keyboard. A1Z26 means that the top letter is T, the bottom letter is B. The letter is a G.

4th character:

> **t** — The missing piece of the grid that i covered by the arrow tile looks like a capital T. This was found by young_nectar and also confirmed by the OP.

5th character:

> **6** — Conerting with a1Z26 gives SIX, or the digit 6.

6th character:

> **D** — This looks like arithmetic with roman numbers: −1 + 10 − 5 = 4. The roman number for 4 is IV, which isn't a single letter. We need a small letter here, so I'm guessing A1Z26 again, which would be D.

7th character:

> **w** — The missing digits are 23. Converting to a letter via A1Z26 gives W.

Comment: Well done, you got 6/7 correct :)

Comment: Thanks. Still no ide why the 4th is a t, though. Is it supposed to mean "top"?

Comment: The square is meant to cover the part of the grid, which looks like 'T'

Comment: Oh! That's neat. (As was the puzzle, by the way.)

Comment: Thanks for the tick, but it was Silenius who found the image.

Comment: Well, you answered first and got 6 out of 7 correct. His first attempt was 3 out of 7 :) Plus, he brute-forced the 4th character which anyone could have done...

Comment: Fair enough. I'll update my answer, so that it has the correct image at least.

Comment: Could not understand A1Z26 means?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused: A1Z26 means to assign a numerical value to each letter according to its position in the alphabet: A is 1, B is 2 and so on until Z is 26. It works both ways: You can turn letters to numbers and vice versa. Closely related is the concept of AZ sum: Sum all A1Z26 values of a word, for example the AZ sum of TEA is 20 + 5 + 1 = 26.

Answer (score 6):

Final answer:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RlfX.jpg

Solutions:

> The arrows indicate whether the character is uppercase or lowercase. If there is no arrow, the character is a digit.

1st character:

> A + B + C + D = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10 = **J**

2nd character:

> **3** (due to [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51600/31484))

3rd character:

> **g** (due to [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51600/31484))

4th character:

> Brute forcing J3g_6dw allows us to find that the 4th character is **t**.

5th character:

> 19 9 24 = SIX = **6**

6th character:

> -I+X-V = -1+10-5 = 4 = **d**

7th character:

> 1 [2 3] 4 5 6 clues the 23rd letter, **w**.

Comment: The answer is correct. Still need an explanation for 4th character :)

Comment: Also, the first letters of title forms an anagram of **ASCII**

Comment: @Silenus For your reference, the explanation for the 1st character has an extraneous digit (probably just got excited while typing, because the conclusion was correct).

Answer (score 3):

The 4th character

> Is a 't' because the lowercase symbol (down arrow) is placed on the vertex that forms a 'T'.
>  [image: Uppercase T]