# How do I feel about the election?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, rebus, knowledge, cryptic-clues

My emotion tied up in one picture. Just click the right link!

> http://imgur.com/■■■■■■■

Each character missing can be any Aa-Zz character or any number 0-9. ([Inspired by this.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51598/solution-is-clearly-an-image))

---

1) Black to black.

[image]

---

2)

[image]

---

3)

[image]

---

4) The penultimate character is missing. Wonder what it is.

[image]

---

5)

[image]

---

6) I was birthed from a Behemoth.

[image]

---

7)

[image]

---

All tags should be appropriate. You'll need them at some point. **So tell me, how am I feeling?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You feel

> EXCITED!

---

The picture is

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOXrc.jpg

1 is

> e, black to black  (@indubitablee)

2 is

> c, its the sea (@indubitablee)

3 is

> j, the shape of the hook (@indubitablee)

4 is

> 4, but needs to be moved to the penultimate position

5 is

> v, lowercase V (@MOehm)

6 is

> Y, head of Yosef(@indubitablee)

7 is

> q, A1Z26

So the picture is

> [image]

Transcription:

> Yciumk fvnmksekmw pvqvz sromk gvdmg

The key is

> [torii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torii) - the type of gate shown (thanks @moehm)

giving

> former referenced being eager seven

or

> Former referenced being eager (7)

Which is

> EXCITED (Ex+cited = being eager)

Answer (score 7):

partial

1. black to black

   > Creates a lower case "**e**"
2. lighthouse image

   > "**c**", as in "sea"
3. fishing scene

   > "**j**" because the fishing hook is bolded compared to the rest of the picture
4. blankness

   > maybe "**s**"? The penultimate character (period considered a character) in the sentence: "The penultimate character is missing. Wonder what it is." The blank image was just a red herring?
5. 2 Vs

   > V/V = **1**?
6. cyclops looking thing

   > "**Y**" for Yosef from Pit People game made by The Behemoth game making crew 
   > http://pitpeople.gamepedia.com/Yosef
   > http://pitpeople.gamepedia.com/Pit_People_Wiki
7. LOWER- Capital V

   > "**v**" the - with the = is supposed to throw us off, it should read Lower - V as in lowercase v?

but that cant be right cause it's not matching with an image.
oh great pse community, lend me your strength, i beseech thee lol.

Comment: With the rebus tag applied, the last could be just a capital L: LOWER − OVER = LV; LV − V = L. Or the digit 5, which is ASCII 55 (LV).

Comment: @MOehm The fact that they are written in capitals is purely a way I tend to write, not important/does not lead to Roman Numerals. Note: the - is important to figuring it out

Comment: Okay to help give a nudge. The letters you have correct are 'e', 'c', 'j', 'Y',